# Border color of pattern image

Tags: php, image, gd

I am working on image manipulation script.

I want to change outline color of the pattern image, not fill up pattern with specific color.

I have tried different method of GD library. I could fill up color of the pattern but could not set outline color of the pattern.

Please let me know if any one has solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

[image: pattern image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// Draw a border 
function drawBorder(&$img, &$color, $thickness = 1) 
{ 
    $x1 = 0; 
    $y1 = 0; 
    $x2 = ImageSX($img) - 1; 
    $y2 = ImageSY($img) - 1; 

    for($i = 0; $i < $thickness; $i++) 
    { 
        ImageRectangle($img, $x1++, $y1++, $x2--, $y2--, $color); 
    } 
}
```

[Credit where due](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/21848-add-border-to-images-with-gd.html#post113807)

You can read about [`imagerectangle()` on the PHP man page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerectangle.php). The key point here is that `$color` must be "A color identifier created with [`imagecolorallocate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php)."

Comment: Thanks for sharing code. Its only change border color of image. I think, I was not clear so much. I need to color outline of pattern.

Comment: Ah, you want to change the color of the lines in the drawing? All of them, or just "border" lines? If the latter, how do you define which ones qualify? This is going to be a very difficult undertaking, involving a lot of math...

Comment: I need to color border line of the pattern. Yes, it could be very difficult.

Comment: You're going to have to do something like this: (1) Find a big empty area (whitespace with no color within a radius of, say, 20 pixels). (2) Find all colored pixels bordering that empty area. (3) Change their color. (4) Figure out how to handle line thicknesses and any edge cases.  (5) Repeat until you run out of big empty areas. Hint for the easy way to do (2) and (3): fill the area with a placeholder color, like hot pink, then only change the color of the existing pixels that have a hot pink neighbor. Then fill the hot pink area back to white.  It's going to be very complex, at best.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to follow this.